# How to Indent a String in Bash using printf?

Tags: bash

Is there an example of indenting strings in Bash (for output)?
I found examples using `printf` but they don't seem to work as expected.
I want to simply indent a given string with a given number of spaces.

```
echo "Header"
indent "Item 1" 2
indent "Sub Item 1a" 4
indent "Sub Item 1b" 4
```

*would produce the output*

```
Header
  Item 1
    Sub Item 1a
    Sub Item 1b
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `printf`, something like `%3s` means "a string, but with as many initial spaces as are necessary to ensure that the string is at least `3` columns wide".

This works even if the string is the empty string `''`, in which case `%3s` means essentially "three spaces".

So, for example, `indent "Sub Item 1a" 4` can be expressed as `printf '%4s%s\n' '' "Sub Item 1a"`, which prints four spaces followed by `"Sub Item 1a"` and a newline.

If you want, you can implement `indent` as a function:

```
function indent () {
    local string="$1"
    local num_spaces="$2"

    printf "%${num_spaces}s%s\n" '' "$string"
}
```

Comment: Have to add the newline in there `printf "%${num_spaces}s%s\n"`